# Duplicate elements of array in ruby

Tags: ruby

I find a lot of reference about removing duplicates in ruby but I cannot find how to create duplicate.

If I have an array like `[1,2,3]` how can I map it to an array with dubbed items? `[1,1,2,2,3,3]`

Is there a method?

Comment: We'd like to see what you've tried. Without evidence of your effort it looks like you didn't do research or tried things, which are required. Please read "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)".

Answer (score 9):

Try this one

```
[1, 2, 3].flat_map { |i| [i, i] }
 => [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
```

Comment: Or more generally: `flat_map { |i| [ i ] * n }` for `n` repetitions.

Answer (score 4):

Here's yet another way, creating the array directly with [`Array#new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-c-new) :

```
array = [1, 2, 3]
repetitions = 2

p Array.new(array.size * repetitions) { |i| array[i / repetitions] }
# [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
```

According to [`fruity`](https://github.com/marcandre/fruity), @ursus's answer, @ilya's first two answers and mine have comparable performance. `transpose.flatten` is slower than any of the others.

Answer (score 3):

@Ursus answer is the most clean, there are possible solutions:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
a.zip(a).flatten
#=> [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
```

Or

```
a.inject([]) {|a, e| a << e << e} #  a.inject([]) {|a, e| n.times {a << e}; a}
=> [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
```

Or

```
[a, a].transpose.flatten # ([a] * n).transpose.flatten
=> [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
```

Comment: A slight variation `a.each_with_object([]) { |e,o| 2.times {o.push e} }`

Comment: @sagarpandya82, thanks for the variation. There are too many possible variants, I prefer mine, it seems more readable :)

Comment: How would you modify the methods to accept an arbitrary number of repetitions?

Comment: @Eric, I added some comments. For the first example it's possible  ( `zip` n times) but looks ugly and slow, let me know if you are still need this :)

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
[1, 2, 3] * 2

 => [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

You might want it sorted:

```
([1, 2, 3] * 2).sort

 => [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
```

Comment: This is by far the most clean version

Comment: You're making some assumptions here. What happens if the array is `[11, 6, 42, 23]`?

Comment: @Ruslan: Nope. This answer might look clean, but it's wrong. What about `[2,1]` or `[1,'2']` ?

Comment: One way around the sorting: `([1, '2'] * 2).sort {|x, y| x.to_s <=> y.to_s}`

Comment: @muistooshort - Maybe you are the one making assumptions. Yes, there is a dearth of information in the question. But making stuff up and saying that is what they have in mind is definitely wrong. Continuing the conversation with Roberto would be good.